# Basic PHP class issue

Tags: php

Going to start again!

I have a form that I use to login.

```
<form method="post" action="user.php">

<label>Username:</label><label class="error"><?php echo $form->error("username"); ?></label>
<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="25" class="text" value="<?php echo $form->value("username"); ?>"/>

<label>Password:</label><label class="error"><?php echo $form->error("password"); ?></label>
<input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $form->value("password"); ?>" class="text" />

<input type="submit" name="login" class="button" value="Login" />
```

This is my user.php file

```
class User {

public function __construct() {

    $this->db = new Database(DB_TYPE, DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

}

public function login() {

    //check username for errors
    $user = $_POST['username'];

    $field = "username";

    //check username isn't empty
    if (empty($user)) {
        $form->setError($field, "* Username not entered");
    }
    //username taken
    else {
        $query = $this->db->select("SELECT userid FROM user WHERE username = :username", array('username' => $user));
        if (!$query) {
            $form->setError($field, "*Username not found");
        }
    }

    //check passwords for error
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $field = "pass";

    //check password isn't empty
    if (empty($pass)) {
        $form->setError($field, "*Password not entered");
    }
    //incorrect password
    else {
        $query = $this->db->select("SELECT userid FROM user WHERE username = :username AND password = :password", array('user' => $user, 'password' => Hash::create('sha256', $pass, HASH_PASSWORD_KEY)));
        if (!$query) {
            $form->setError($field, "*Password not found");
        }
    }

    //if errors exist, return to user - otherwise insert into db
    if ($form->num_errors > 0) {
        return 1;  //Errors with form
    } 
    else{

        //use the userid and set it as session variable
        $query = $this->db->select("SELECT userid FROM user WHERE username = :username AND password = :password", array('user' => $user, 'password' => Hash::create('sha256', $pass, HASH_PASSWORD_KEY)));
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $query[0]['userid'];

        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

        header("Location ".URL."dashboard.php");
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, I use `$form` which is in form.php.

What's the best way to access this class from the form itself?

Thanks.

Comment: Matt's right. Yet... are those `//` comments in there for a reason?

Comment: Please also share the code where you declare an `User` object

Comment: As a side note, this kind of code shouldn't even be inside your User constructor.

Comment: Also, describe what the actual problem is. You haven't really mentioned what is or is not happening.

Comment: well where are you initialising the object .. ?

Comment: Think I've got a bit confused here! I have a login function within my user class that I want to access from the login form?

Comment: See the answers, they describe clearly what the issue is

Comment: The answer didn't fix it. It still doesn't find its way!

Comment: Then maybe you could describe what error you get?

Comment: Sorry about my vagueness. When I process the form, I'm just getting a blank screen. I believe what I need is to just access a static function, rather than an object? It's a very basic script. Is it possible to get access to one of the functions from the form itself?

Comment: Seriously, take a break. This hardly makes any sense.

Comment: I've just realised this is probably the worst question ever seen on SO.

Comment: Oh no, not by a long shot. It's in the same ballpark though. ;P

Comment: Haha I've made a genuine attempt to make it a bit better!!

Comment: You are aware that you need to ***instantiate*** the class at some point? Just a class definition by itself does nothing.

Comment: I just think I've lost the plot bud. It's 7am here and I've been doing it since about 8pm last night. Best just call it a day, don't know what I'm doing now!

Answer (score 4):

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $this->login();
}
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    $this->register();
}
else{
    $this->logout();
}
```

Logout will always get executed. This is because $_POST['register'] is not set, and the else condition is always taken. Change the second `if` to `else if`.

Comment: So very well spotted, wish I could give you +5